# Triggering iron python script linked to a spotfire control element with jquery

Tags: jquery, ironpython, spotfire

I have a html designed textarea (along the lines of a KPI tile) with a spotfire contol in place (the KPI value). Right now, the functionality is that when the spotfire control is clicked, the visualizations on the template change based on a ironpython script.

I want to extend this functionality so that by clicking on anywhere on the html KPI tile, the contol click is triggered.

I am able to capture the click event on the HTML element, but when i trigger a click event on the SF element, the desired action is not being triggered.

Eg:

```
$(".kpivalue").click(function(){
   this.children("SpotfireControl").trigger("click");
});
```

```
<DIV class=kpivalue><SpotfireControl id="1234567890xxx" /></DIV>
```

Answer (score 1):

I answered a bit too quickly earlier. oops!

controls are not rendered as  elements; these are placeholders or tokens that get replaced with HTML when rendered.

in the case of a Caluclated Value, the generated DOM looks like:

```html
<div id="myContainerDiv">
  <span id="randomGUID1" style>
    <span id="randomGUID2" viewid="randomGUID2" class="EmbeddedMiniatureVisualization" ...>
      <span class="actionCell" style="...">theCalculatedValueValue</span>
    </span>
  </span>
</div>
```

thus, when you want to target the actual Calculated Value, you'd need something like

```js
$("#myContainerDiv").click(function(){
   $(this).children("actionCell").trigger("click");
});
```

---

<s>since Spotfire's DOM can be a little weird, you have to be a little weird yourself :) my understanding is that `.trigger("click")` will trigger a click on a JQuery element, but not the actual DOM. for that you'll need something like:</s>

```
$(".kpivalue").click(function(){
   this.children("SpotfireControl")[0].click();
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. But unfortunately, this is not working. Is there any good reference for the way spotfire generates the DOM.

Comment: you can enable Developer Tools in the options menu, and then use Tools>>Development>>Developer tools. this will give you access to the entire DOM in literally a Chromium DOM inspector :) meantime I'll try to come up with a better, more functioning answer